# Create a new column in SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create a new column in a SQL query results? I'm thinking of expanding my movie database to handle multiple users. I have a table with the basic movie details such as title type plot rating year released and have a table with a list of movie Ids and user ids for the movies that a user has marked as watched. I would like to generate a list for a user and to show if it has been watched or not by said user.

Ex
The matrix watched
The matrix 2 
Or 
The matrix 2 un-watched

Or would it be a better idea to create a table that has a list of movie ids nada user idea and a status column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new table

This is a [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) table relationship

this table should contain userID and movieID

I think you dont need a status column (if watched, there is a line / if not, there is nothing)

Comment: I knew I could do that, but I didn't know if that was the best way to do it or not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is surely the best solution

Comment: This is the most sensible way to do it in a relational database. It could be done in other ways (more or less de-normalized), but it's likely that if you needed those, you'd know it. :)

Answer (score 2):

So, you have users and movies. A user could've watched many movies. A single movie could've been watched by many users. This means it's a **many-to-many relationship.**

That's a standard problem. The solution:

1. `movies` table - movie id, title, type etc. - you got that already
2. `users_to_movies` - user id, movie id, status (or e.g. date watched, NULL if not watched), any other data if need be
3. `users` - user id, name, last name, e-mail - whatever you need there.

The primary key in `users_to_movies` is a compound key, consisting of two columns: (`user_id`, `movie_id`).

The table `users_to_movies` is an **association table**. This is the "bridge" between two tables that are in a **many-to-many** relationship.

**Example:**

User with id 5 watched Matrix 2 (id 12 in `movies` table) on 4th Sep 6pm. So you `INSERT INTO users_to_movies VALUES(5, 12, '2014-04-09')`. If you want to store the information that user id 2 hasn't watched Matrix 2, you insert `(2, 12, NULL`).